# What's the intention of forward-by-lvalue-reference constructor while a perfect forwarding constructor exists?

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Let's take `std::pair<T1, T2>` as an example. It has the following two constructors:

```
constexpr pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );                      // #1
template< class U1, class U2 > constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y ); // #2
```

It seems that #2 can handle all cases that #1 can handle (without worse performance), except for cases where an argument is a list-initializer. For example,

```
std::pair<int, int> p({0}, {0}); // ill-formed without #1
```

So my question is:

- If #1 is only intended for list-initializer argument, since `x` and `y` finally bind to temporary objects initialized from list-initializers, why not use `constexpr pair( T1&& x, T2&& y );` instead?
- Otherwise, what's the actual intention of #1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if the object you want to store is a temporary one but is not movable ?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class   test
{
public:
  test() { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }
  test(const test&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
  test(test&&) = delete; // { std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl; }
  ~test() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }

private:
  int dummy;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class   my_pair
{
public:
  my_pair() {}
  // Uncomment me plz !
  //my_pair(const T1& x, const T2& y) : first(x), second(y) {}
  template <class U1, class U2, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U1, T1>::value && std::is_convertible<U2, T2>::value>::type>
  my_pair(U1&& x, U2&& y) : first(std::forward<U1>(x)), second(std::forward<U2>(y)) {}

public:
  T1 first;
  T2 second;
};

int     main()
{
  my_pair<int, test>    tmp(5, test());
}
```

The above code doesn't compile because the so called "perfect" forwarding constructor of `my_pair` forwards the temporary `test` object as an rvalue reference which in turn tries to call the explicitly deleted move constructor of `test`.

If we remove the comment from `my_pair`'s not so "perfect" constructor it is preferred by overload resolution and basically forces the copy of the temporary `test` object and thus makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question.

`pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );` was there *before* the forwarding constructor was added in C++17. The `constexpr` was added in C++14. Now why keep the constructor around? Two reasons: 1) backwards compatibility and 2) because as you said, perfectly well-formed code would refuse to compile. C++ has a heavy emphasis on backwards compatibility and takes a very conservative approach to deprecating code because it can break in unexpected ways.

Now if you want a more realistic example, try `std::for_each`. You can change it to perfect forward a functor without any breakage in code. However, there's little incentive to add this change because it's specified to make only exactly one copy. In other words, the change is not very high priority.

Comment: The forwarding constructor was added in C++11. I don't think `std::for_each` is a good example because functor is often cheap to copy.