# Why does `std::pair` allow to initialize from an rvalue of class type with a user-defined deleted move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move-semantics, std-pair

Consider the following class:

```
struct Do_not_move {
    Do_not_move() = default;
    Do_not_move(const Do_not_move&) = default;
    Do_not_move(Do_not_move&&) = delete;
private:
    int dummy;
};
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094141/5376789) I learn that `std::pair` (as well as `std::tuple`) allows to initialize from an `Do_not_move` rvalue, e.g.

```
Do_not_move dnm;
std::pair<int, Do_not_move> p(0, std::move(dnm)); // work well
```

However, many other STL classes reject such use. For example,

```
Do_not_move dnm;
std::vector<Do_not_move> v{std::move(dnm)}; // error
std::set<Do_not_move> s{std::move(dnm)};    // error
std::any a{std::move(dnm)};                 // error
```

I do know why these behaviors occur. My question is, why is `std::pair` designed to be so special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do know why these behaviors occur ...

Nope - in your example you're invoking `std::vector::vector(std::initializer_list)` and `std::set::set(std::initializer_list)`. Unfortunately `std::initializer_list<T>` is basically sugar over a `const T[]` array - this means that you cannot move from an `initializer_list`.

`std::any a{std::move(dnm)};` compiles fine - [live example on wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RSKa98ISxbdEsKT8).

---

> why `std::pair` is designed to be so special?

It's not. It just happens to have both these constructors:

```
constexpr pair( const T1& x, const T2& y ); // (0)

template <typename U1, typename U2>
constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );  // (1)
```

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), these constructors are SFINAE-friendly *(i.e. they will not participate in overload resolution if the construction is invalid)*.

When invoking

```
std::pair<int, Do_not_move> p(0, std::move(dnm));
```

first we try to use **(1)**, which is invalid. It gets SFINAE'd out, so that **(0)** remains. That one is fine as `T&&` binds to `const T&`, and it performs a copy.

If I had to **guess** *why* `std::pair` has both these constructors: the class was available before *forwarding references* were invented and it only exposed **(0)**. When *forwarding references* were introduced into the language, **(1)** was added to `std::pair`. Probably in order to preserve backwards-compatibility, the constructors were designed to be SFINAE-friendly.

Comment: `std::any` case fails under Clang... I think Clang is right because `std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<Do_not_move>>` is `true`, so the forward constructor of `std::any` is enabled and be chosen in overload resolution, thus fails because of trying to move.